# Help with layout problems in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I am having some problems getting [this layout](http://louiswalch.com/beta/gp5my89/) to work properly in IE (both 6 and 7). It, of course, works fine in Safari and Firefox.

**What's going on here:**

- I have a footer which is fixed to the bottom of the viewport, or under content - whichever is longer.
- I have a header above the content which contains a number of centered and floated block items, which is wider then the content area.
- I have a centered fixed width content area

**The problems**

- (Main problem) In IE7 a horizontal scroll bar appears because of the floated header.
- In IE6 the footer does not snap below content area.

Any insight would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're positioning the footer by making layout extend the full height and then giving it a negative bottom margin to shift the footer up . . . perhaps getting rid of the negative margin and using relative positioning on the footer to shift it up would be more cross-browser compatible.

I haven't actually tried this out with your page, it's just a thought.

UPDATE:
Turns out `position: relative` isn't all that great . . . it makes the scrollbar extend to where the footer would have been without the repositioning.

But try applying `#footer{position: absolute; bottom: 0px; width: 100%}` and get rid of the negative bottom margin of layout . . . this works for me at least in Firefox, I haven't yet checked IE.

Comment: For instance: `#footer{position: relative; top: -42px}`

Alternatively you could use absolute positioning on the footer:
`#footer{position:absolute; bottom: 0px}`

Comment: Tim, thanks for the reply. Do you have any idea about my first problem - the horizontal scrollbar appearing for ie because of the center floated header? That is the one I am most concerned about.

Comment: try this css:  `body{overflow-x: hidden;}`

For more info on the CSS overflow property, see here: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: In the CSS, try removing `left: 50%` from `#layout #header` and also removing `left: -50%` from `#layout #header UL#mainmenu`

Comment: That would make it not center the floated elements.

Comment: You can shift them back to the right by adding something like `left: 5%` to `#layout #header UL#mainmenu`.

I'll think about if there's another way to guarantee they're exactly centered (other than just eyeballing it).

Comment: Ooh, here's a better idea:
Just add `position: relative` to `#layout #header_wrap'.

I think with this approach you can leave the centering stuff as you had it originally.

Comment: Ahh bingo The position:relative; was the key. Thanks.